# Высота тега html body

Tags: html, css

Как правильно указать высоту блокам `html` и `body`?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>App</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <header class="header"></header>
            <main class="main">
            
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <p class="card-title">404</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
            </main>
            <footer class="footer"></footer>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

В чем разница в данных подходах? И какой предпочтительный вариант для использования?

```
html, body {
    min-height: 100%;
    // или
    height: 100%;
    // или
    height: 100vh;
}
```

Comment: Как и зачем вы хотите указать высоту тэга <html>?

Comment: И еще, вы зачем-то дублируете height. Первый раз прописываете вообще в %. В 100% от чего?

Comment: Или связку `html { height: 100%; } body { min-height: 100%; } `, или просто `body { min-height: 100vh; }`.

Answer (score 1):

Теперь понятно, что вы имеете ввиду

```
min-height: 100%;
```

Это значит, что минимальная высота блока - 100% от родительского. А так как у body по определению не может быть родительского блока, соответственно это не верно

```
height: 100%;
```

Тоже самое, только не минимальная. Опять же 100% непонятно от чего

```
height: 100vh;
```

Из предоставленных вами вариантов - этот самый адекватный

Comment: _"у body по определению не может быть родительского блока"_ Тег `<html>` не в счёт?

Comment: @UModeL, ладно вы меня подловили. Но, согласитесь, что указывать высоту у html тэга - не очень хорошая практика

Comment: Значит, фротэндеры SO и Яндекса - плохие практики ;-)

Comment: @UModeL
html, body {
 height: 100vh;
}
А вот так можно или только в процентах? И почему body { min-height: 100vh; } так будет работать (явно не указывается html)?

Comment: @Yeyy используйте в body min-height:100vh; и не парьтесь, 100% работать не будет, так как не от чего брать процент. И вообще body 100vh нужно только если вы решили например footer прижать к низу экрана вне зависимости от высоты контента или background сделать картинкой. В других случаях не нужно заморачиваться.